# Contact user using Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am developing an android game with Google Play Game Services implemented in it. I'm using leaderboard from game services. Every week I want to award users with highest ranking with some gifts. Is there any way to get users email or different channel to contact user, so we will be able to determine where we should ship the gift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is not a documented feature. You can use `Games.Leaderboards.loadTopScores` to get top scores. When you have a `LeaderboardScore` object you can use `score.getScoreHolder().getPlayerId()` to get his Google+ id. Then open https://plus.google.com/PUT_ID_HERE/posts and you can contact that player via Hangouts.